# Realizar consulta mysql de duas tabelas via php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-select

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou com um problema que já não sei mais como resolver.

Tenho a seguinte consulta mysql em php:

```
mysql_select_db("banco", $conexao);
    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE id = '" . $cod . "'");
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
```

Isso funciona.

Mas preciso pegar os dados de outra tabela referenciada na tabela pessoa.
A tabela pessoa tem uma coluna com chave estrangeira da tabela veiculo.

Se eu coloco o sql abaixo no PhpMyAdmin para testar, funciona :

```
SELECT p.id, p.nome, v.modelo FROM pessoa p
INNER JOIN veiculo v ON p.veiculo = v.id
WHERE p.id = 17
```

Agora se pego esse sql e coloco no php dá erro:

```
mysql_select_db("banco", $conexao);
    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT p.id, p.nome, v.modelo FROM pessoa p INNER JOIN veiculo v ON p.veiculo = v.id WHERE p.id = '" . $cod . "'");
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
```

Isso já me consumiu o dia! O que posso estar errando?

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Não devia ser `INNER JOIN veiculo AS v`? falta aí um `AS` e o mesmo em `FROM pessoa p` que deve ser `FROM pessoa AS p`

Comment: A alias, dependendo da versão do MySQL, pode ser referenciado sem o termo AS. Mas particularmente não vejo como boa prática.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma pergunta, toda pessoa obrigatoriamente possui um veículo?

Use da maneira simplificada (sem JOIN) e veja se funciona, caso contrário nos informe o erro gerado:

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.nome,
  v.modelo
FROM
  pessoa p,
  veiculo v 
WHERE p.veiculo = v.id 
  AND p.id = 17
```

Usando LEFT JOIN (respeitando a tabela pessoa):

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.nome,
  v.modelo 
FROM
  pessoa p 
  LEFT JOIN veiculo v 
    ON p.veiculo = v.id 
WHERE p.id = 17
```

Procure também utilizar o SQL já com o id definido (17), sem passar por parâmetro, muitas vezes o erro pode ser seu `$id` também.

Espero que ajude

Comment: obrigada. Resolveu meu problema de vez!

Comment: para mais uma tabela, seria isso: SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.nome,
  v.modelo
  m.marca
FROM
  pessoa p,
  veiculo v ,
  marca m
WHERE p.veiculo = v.id 
  AND p.marca = m.marca
  AND p.id = 17

Comment: Exato @MarciaPereiraReis :D